Обращение к содержащемуся в ListView элементу управления
У меня на форме есть ListView, содержащий в себе элемент управления TextBox.
<ListView x:Name="listDatas" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="167" Margin="10,40,10,0" FontSize="11">
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Width="115">Имя
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>

Вопрос: как мне через код C# обратиться к TextBox и записать в него какой-либо текст?

По идеологии WPF вы наверное должны забиндить на этот ListView источник данных, а не менять вручную отдельные TextBox внутри него.

Моя программа предназначена для работы с разными источниками данных (базами данных), от чего записи в textbox и кол-во этих записей заранее не определено.

Вы не должны хотеть через C# код трогать UI (XAML). Вам выше верно сказали - привяжите все и работайте с данными, с простыми классами. "Динамичный источник данных" - это теж самые классы, но только абстрагированные (интерфейсы, абстрактные классы, и так далее). Ну вот допустим interface IItem { string Text { get; } } далее class Item : IItem { public string Text { get; set; } }. Теперь делаете коллекцию: public ObservableCollection<IItem> Items {get;} = new();, ну а в XAML <ListView ItemsSource = "{Binding Items}">...<TextBox Text = "{Binding Text}"/>. Изменение: Items[0].Text = ...;

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, можно перечислять бесконечно огромную кучу примеров привязки данных к ListView здесь.

aepot, спасибо вам большое!
